# how to prevent other users on the network who know my IP from accessing pages other than I want them to?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost

I use LAN in my hostel and I have built a website. Now I am hosting it on localhost/xampp and now to launch it I am providing, other users over the LAN, my "IP/website_ directory_name".

It works fine till here. 
Now the trouble is, if any user simply deletes the "website_ directory_name" part from the URL then the homepage of xampp opens and thus the user gets complete access to "phpmyadmin". Now he can do anything (malicious) with my databases.

So, how can I prevent the user from having access to this. And how do I restrict him have access only inside my "website_ directory_name" folder??

Any help is thoroughly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set up a password to access your "phpadmin". That'll do it!

Answer (score 0):

Create an index.html file in your www(localhost) folder which contains some texts which will be the default page whenever trying with the ip without any specific folder names as url. And in order to restrict the users to the folders, provide the htaccess files in the respective folders.